# UIView automatically reset to old frame after setting value from DatePicker to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uitextfield, swift2

Facing strange issue in swift. I making one demo that contain registration form and create on `UIView` in `storyBoard` and when user select Date TextField I am open this view using animation using following code:

```
UIView .animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.viewDate.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen .mainScreen().bounds.size.height - self.viewDate.frame.size.height, self.viewDate.frame.size.width, self.viewDate.frame.size.height)
            })
```

After change value in `DatePicker` that following method called:

```
@IBAction func select_BirthDate(sender:AnyObject) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
        self.txtBirthDate.text = strDate
        print("Date is : \(strDate)")
    }
```

But Strange issue is that when `select_BirthDate` called and set its date in `UITextField` that appear view automatically disappear I didn't code for change it's frame and if i am comment `self.txtBirthDate.text = strDate` all things working parfect. even if I set value in `UITextView` then also working fine. issue only with `UITextFiled` I did not use any Layout for appear UIview.

[image]

[HERE IT IS DEMO PROJECT LINK](http://ge.tt/6UTVCMP2/v/0)

Comment: I did some testing. The problem is the autolayout, if you uncheck the autolayout everything works fine. I think the autolayout is taking the view to its original location when selection event occour, but could not identify why this is happening. Anyway, if you will not use autolayout, you should not be marked.Or you can use autolayout and animate the constraint